# How can I identify an unusual character in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: unicode, sublime-text-3

I have a file with an unusual Unicode grapheme. I'd like to identify it, either by getting an info window directly in Sublime, or just by listing the codepoint(s) so I can search for them online.

In Vim, I'd use the `ga` command to view the Unicode codepoint, or possibly `g8` to view the bytes, and then google for that to get the name of the character and other relevant information.

Is there a way to get this information in Sublime? An equivalent to Vim's `ga` would suffice, but a more elaborate solution that shows more information within Sublime itself (so I don't need to google) would be good. I'm open to installing a plugin to achieve this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you go to **`File -> Reopen with Encoding -> Hexadecimal`** you'll be able to get the hex codepoint from there. Unfortunately, Sublime's built-in hex viewer doesn't include a plain-text counterpart on the side, so unless the character is one of the only ones in the file, you might have a bit of a time with it. Instead, you might want to check out the [`HexViewer`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/HexViewer) plugin from facelessuser. It's much more of a full-featured hex viewer like you'd find in a standalone program, and should fit your needs quite nicely.

Comment: A quick additional: do these options work only with files (like in the question), or also with text I'm pasting into an empty buffer?

Comment: @DanHulme apparently you need to save the file to disk first. I just tried to invoke HexViewer on a fresh view with some random text, and it gave me an error that the view doesn't exist on disk. As a workaround you could always just quickly save the view to `/tmp` or `C:\temp` or wherever.

Comment: If you have questions or concerns, connect to the Github repo through the Package Control page I linked and open an issue. I know the developer, and he's usually quite responsive.